# Eliminar una fila de mi tabla

Tags: php, sql

Quiero eliminar una fila de mi tabla y ello lo quiero hacer mediante un `form` en el cual le digo el id de esa fila.

¿Porque me dice que no he definido el valor? Es decir, ¿no se recoge así?

```
$valor = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['idEliminar']);
```

**Error**

> Notice: Undefined index: idEliminar in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP_WEB_MMR\P3\PHP\eliminar.php on line 12

**Código**

```html
<form action="PHP/eliminar.php">
  <input type="text" name="idEliminar" placeholder="ID del usuario a eliminar" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Eliminar">
</form>
```

```
<?PHP

    // Conectamos con la base de datos LOCAL
    $bd_host = "localhost"; 
    $bd_usuario = "root"; 
    $bd_password = ""; 
    $bd_base = "carrot";

    $conexion = mysqli_connect($bd_host, $bd_usuario, $bd_password, $bd_base);  

    // Recojo los datos del formulario - NOTAR EL USO DE LA FUNCIÓN DE ESCAPADO
    $valor = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['idEliminar']);

    // Hacemos la consulta. En este caso queremos eliminar el usuario registrado
    $consulta = "DELETE FROM usuarios_pass WHERE id = $valor";

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

    // Liberamos y cerramos conexión.
    //mysqli_free_result($resultado);
    //mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Como veis he tenido que comentar

```
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
```

porque como siempre me da error, el cual por mucho que leo y me explican no entiendo.

Se que debe ser muy básico pero la verdad que el tema de PHP+SQL se me estáhaciendo un mundo.

Salud!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás tratando de obtener un indice de `POST` cuando tu form no lo especificas como `POST`

```
<form action="PHP/eliminar.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="idEliminar" placeholder="ID del usuario a eliminar" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Eliminar">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

El formulario se envía por defecto con GET, pero estás leyendo el `$_POST`.

Puedes recoger el valor usando `$_REQUEST["idEliminar"];` en su lugar.